# ASP.NET view exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2

```
     Function Edit(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult


        Dim entities As New Deployment_devEntities()
        Dim w As System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery(Of tblWebsites) = entities.CreateQuery(Of tblWebsites)("SELECT VALUE m FROM tblWebsites as m WHERE m.WebsiteID = " & id)

        Dim q = From m In entities.tblWebsites Where m.WebsiteID = id Select m

        Return View(q.Single())

    End Function
```

I have a strong typed view of type EntityFrameworkTest.tblWebsites when I pass in the results using either Linq to Entity or Entity SQL I get this error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[EntityFrameworkTest.tblWebsites]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'EntityFrameworkTest.tblWebsites'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

The code is example only.

Comment: You're declaring an ObjectQuery (`w`), but you never use it? Why?

Comment: As stated in comments below-- we're getting hung up trying to debug your problem without seeing the actual (relevant) code.  Can you paste your controller code and at least the top part of the View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your view needs to inherit from `IEnumerable<tblWebsites>` or you need to change your controller to return a single instance of `tblWebsites`.  You can do this with the LINQ `.FirstOrDefault()` method.

Comment: Thanks, Paul.  I missed the .Single().

Comment: The answer is not wrong, though. Despite the `Single()` in the demo code, the error indicates he's indeed returning a list in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally do VB if I can avoid it, it looks to me like your code is inferring the type (and coming up with the assumption that it's an objectquery).  Try calling .Single(Of tblWebsites) instead of just Single().  Or casting.

Answer (score 0):

Your action is returning a list, but your view expects 1 object. Figure out which one of these is wrong and fix it.

Comment: his naming's all screwed up, but it looks like a "tblWebsites" is a single object.

Comment: He's passing a list. That's what ObjectQuery`1[[EntityFrameworkTest.tblWebsite] means. True, that doesn't correspond with his demo code, but he says the code isn't real, so I tend to believe the exception rather than his fake demo code.

Comment: Fair enough, I was making the possibly erroneous assumption that his demo code was syntactically the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the .Single() is not supported by LINQ to Entities.
Using .FirstOrDefault() or .First() worked fine.

Thank you all.